# Possible to programmatically add User Control to Silverlight Grid Column?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a User Control that I need to programmatically add to a Silverlight Grid t a specified Row and Column index.  The requirements are such that I will need to insert at arbitrary indices, such that pure databinding is perhaps not ideal.

I would prefer not to have to create the grid from scratch in the code behind.
Can this be done?  Anyone with example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use Grid.Children.Add to add it to the grid, and Grid.SetRow and Grid.SetColumn to set the row and column index.  E.g.

```
Grid.SetRow(myControl, 3);
Grid.SetColumn(myControl, 4);
myGrid.Children.Add(myControl);
```