# Append Child control inside a Border in Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, border

I want to append a child control (button) programmatically inside a border left corner at run time based on event of a check box. my code on check box true value:

```
var btn = new System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton();
btn.Style = App.Current.Resources["ToggleButtonStyle"] as Style;
ctrlBorder.Child = btn;
ctrlBorder.Tag = btn;
```

Now the issue is if i am adding as child, all other controls inside the control as invisible and only btn is displayed. How can I append a btn inside a border control.
Also, on unchecking the checkbox the btn should disappear.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should first add a layout Panel (e.g. a StackPanel or a Grid) to the Border, then add new elements to the Children collection of the Panel.

Answer (score 0):

By assigning `ctrlBorder.Child` you overwrite its only child (one allowed for border control). Try to append your control to the actual child of the border (Grid? StackPanel?)

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1871229/1346098 :

```
Grid tmpGrid = ctrlBorder.Child as Grid;
tmpGrid.SetRow(btn, 3);
tmpGrid.SetColumn(btn, 4);
tmpGrid.Children.Add(btn);
```